# Showing Remainders instead of Entirety

Tags: java

So I need to write a program that tells how long a specific-sized file will download at a specific rate.

```
// get user input 
System.out.print("Enter file size (MB): "); 
double fileSize = sc.nextDouble(); 

//get user input 
System.out.print("Enter download speed (MB/sec): "); 
double downloadSpeed = sc.nextDouble(); 
.
.
code body is here
.
.
String message = 
"This download will take approximately\n" + number.format(totalHours) 
    + " hours\n" + number.format(totalMinutes) + " minutes\n" 
    + number.format(totalSeconds) + " seconds\n" ; 
System.out.println(message);
```

So that's the basic idea. you enter the desired file size and the desired download rate and it tells you how long it will take to download at the given rate. So I want to know how to make it do i don't get results like:

```
Welcome to the Download Time Estimator

Enter file size (MB): 20000
Enter download speed (MB/sec): 5.0
This download will take approximately
1 hours
67 minutes
4,000 seconds

Continue? (y/n):
```

How can I make it so it gives a remainder in the results? (60 minutes in an hour and 60 seconds in a minute) Does this make sense?
here is my code right now:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.text.NumberFormat;

public class DownloadTimeApp
{

   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
       // welcome the user to the program 
       System.out.println("Welcome to the Download Time Estimator"); 
       System.out.println(); // print a blank line 

       // create Scanner object and start a while loop 
       Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); 
       String choice = "y"; 
       while (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) 
       { 
           // get user input 
           System.out.print("Enter file size (MB): "); 
           double fileSize = sc.nextDouble(); 

           //get user input 
           System.out.print("Enter download speed (MB/sec): "); 
           double downloadSpeed = sc.nextDouble(); 

           // calculate the hour, minutes and seconds 
           double totalSeconds; 
           double totalMinutes; 
           double totalHours; 
           int hour; 
           int minutes = 60; 
           int seconds = 60; 


           totalSeconds = fileSize / downloadSpeed; 
           totalMinutes = (totalSeconds)/60; 
           totalHours = (totalSeconds)/3600; 

           NumberFormat number = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(); 
           number.setMaximumFractionDigits(0); 

           String message = 
           "This download will take approximately\n" + 
           number.format(totalHours) 
           + " hours\n" + number.format(totalMinutes) + " minutes\n" 
           + number.format(totalSeconds) + " seconds\n" ; 
           System.out.println(message); 

           // see if the user wants to continue 
           System.out.print("Continue? (y/n): "); 
           choice = sc.next(); 
           System.out.println();
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Why did you tag javascript if the question is only about java?

Answer (score 1):

In Java, there is the modulus function which uses the % operator. You can use this like when you would division and you will get the remainder instead of the division result. For example, your minutes could be `minutesDisplayed = minutes % 60`in order to get what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

**is this what you are looking for?:**

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.text.NumberFormat;

public class DownloadTimeApp
{

   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
       // welcome the user to the program 
       System.out.println("Welcome to the Download Time Estimator"); 
       System.out.println(); // print a blank line 

       // create Scanner object and start a while loop 
       Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); 
       String choice = "y"; 
       while (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) 
       { 
           // get user input 
           System.out.print("Enter file size (MB): "); 
           double fileSize = sc.nextDouble(); 

           //get user input 
           System.out.print("Enter download speed (MB/sec): "); 
           double downloadSpeed = sc.nextDouble(); 

           // calculate the hour, minutes and seconds 
           double totalSeconds; 
           double totalMinutes; 
           double totalHours; 
           int hour; 
           int minutes = 60; 
           int seconds = 60; 


           totalSeconds = fileSize / downloadSpeed; 
           totalMinutes = ((totalSeconds)/60)%60; 
           totalHours = (totalSeconds)/3600; 
           totalSeconds - totalSeconds % 60;
           NumberFormat number = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(); 
           number.setMaximumFractionDigits(0); 

           String message = 
           "This download will take approximately\n" + 
           number.format(totalHours) 
           + " hours\n" + number.format(totalMinutes) + " minutes\n" 
           + number.format(totalSeconds) + " seconds\n" ; 
           System.out.println(message); 

           // see if the user wants to continue 
           System.out.print("Continue? (y/n): "); 
           choice = sc.next(); 
           System.out.println();
       }
   }
}
```

As mentioned in previous answer, in java there is a modulus operator `%`,
which is perfect to this kind of jobs like extracting the seconds remainding to full minutes, or minutes remainding to full hour.
basically the % operator calculates the result like this:

```
1%60=1;
2%60=2;
3%60=3;
...
61%60=1;
62%60=2;
63%60=3;
...
121%60=1;
122%60=2;
123%60=3;
...
and so on...and so on...
```

Answer (score 1):

Use some `while` statements to break down each totalSeconds, totalMinutes, and totalHours into numbers that reflect the whole download time.

Using some in your code would look like

```js
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.text.NumberFormat;

public class DownloadTimeApp
{

   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
       // welcome the user to the program 
       System.out.println("Welcome to the Download Time Estimator"); 
       System.out.println(); // print a blank line 

       // create Scanner object and start a while loop 
       Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); 
       String choice = "y"; 
       while (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) 
       { 
           // get user input 
           System.out.print("Enter file size (MB): "); 
           double fileSize = sc.nextDouble(); 

           //get user input 
           System.out.print("Enter download speed (MB/sec): "); 
           double downloadSpeed = sc.nextDouble(); 

           // calculate the hour, minutes and seconds 
           int totalSeconds = 0; 
           int totalMinutes = 0; 
           int totalHours = 0; 
           /*int hour; 
           int minutes = 60; 
           int seconds = 60;*/
           //^^ Useless information


           totalSeconds = fileSize / downloadSpeed; 
           while (totalSeconds >= 60) {
              totalMinutes = totalMinutes + 1;
              totalSeconds = totalSeconds - 60;
           }
           while (totalMinutes >= 60) {
              totalHours = totalHours + 1;
              totalMinutes = totalMinutes - 60;
           }
           //Add same thing for days if you'd like

           /*NumberFormat number = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(); 
           number.setMaximumFractionDigits(0);*/
           //^^ Useless formatting

           String message = 
           "This download will take approximately\n" + 
           totalHours + " hours\n" +
           totalMinutes + " minutes\n" +
           totalSeconds + " seconds\n" ; 
           System.out.println(message); 

           // see if the user wants to continue 
           System.out.print("Continue? (y/n): "); 
           choice = sc.next(); 
           System.out.println();
       }
   }
}
```

If you put in fileSize as 1000MB and downloadSpeed as 10MB/sec, then you would have

```
totalSeconds = 40;
totalMinutes = 1;
totalHours   = 0;
```